# Vimeo API - get all videos from a channel

Tags: get, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'd like to get all Vimeo's videos from a channel.

I looked to [the Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start), created [a key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wwy9aibAd54) for my app but I found no simple method to get all videos with for example the id of the channel...

How to do that ?

Thx.

Answer (score 4):

To get the list of videos in a channel, make an authenticated GET request to `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/[channel_id]/videos`. The endpoint documentation can be found here: [https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/channels#GET/channels/{channel_id}/videos](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/channels#GET/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/videos)

If you don't know the channel_id of a channel, you can substitute the id with the custom url of the channel. For instance, with the Staff Picks channel at https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks, make an authenticated GET request to `https://api.vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks`

That said, it's best practice to use the channel_id instead of the shortcut url name wherever possible. The Staff Picks channel, for example, returns `"uri":"/channels/927"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Can you get the `channel_id` a different way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct, but I found myself looking for a solution on how to get the channel id.

There two options(that I found) to get the channel id

1. If you have access to run js in the browser(like in Puppeteer) - run the following js

```
vimeo.config.channel.id
```

and it will return the id of the channel.

2. Another option is to get it via regex
   `\"channel\"\:\{\"id\"\:\"(\d*)\"`

It's taking the following part from the  tag

```
vimeo.config = _extend((vimeo.config || {}), {"channel":{"id":"164226","url":"\/channels\/fenwn"},"sticky_topnav":{"excluded_pages":["Vimeo\\Controller\\AboutController:main","Vimeo\\Controller\\AboutController:profe
```